# Pushkit VoiP push notifications wake up app execution time

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

When I receive VoIP push notification while app is removed from the background (using developer APNS), my app wakes up for like 10 minutes. 
When I do the same thing, just this time using production APNS, my app wakes up for 8-10 seconds. 
What's the trick there? Why production version of the application can't be woken up for at least 30 seconds? Is there any way to extend wake up time, since 10 sec is not eough for all work I have to do?

## EDIT

At the end background time wasn't problem. My app was crashing when completely removed form background and woken up by voip notif. I was thinking that it wasn't crash but limited execution time. When I fixed that crash everything was working as it should.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was a development certificate for the VoIP Services certificate. I only have a production certificate. Make sure you are not mistaken the APNS certificate for the VoIP certificate. To check you can kill the app (double tap home button and swipe app away) and check if push message is still received by the app. If not, it's not the VoIP certificate.

Comment: Also if you send a lot of VoIP push messages and woke up the app a lot then the iOS operating system will deduce that from the budget resulting in the app being waken up only for a short period of time. Give the app a rest and test again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke your app in background while app is in terminated state. Then you can keep Local notification based on pushkit payload.

Also keep sound file in local notification.

So your app will be active in background even if app is been terminated.

App will be active upto local notification sound plays (Max 30 seconds).

Within that duration achieve your things.

**Note** Your app must have valid category and permissions from Apple to consume pushkit silent notification. Because pushkit is strongly recommended for VOIP based apps only. If your app is not VOIP based then contact Apple for required permission.

Refer pushkit example if you are not aware.

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: so which method will be called after 30s?

Comment: None method will be called after 30 seconds, interaction event with local notification like cancel accept etc will be invoke on tap event. Let me whT exactly you are looking.

Comment: That sounds unfortunate!!  I must do something before inactive even if I don't tap on the local notification!  How can I do this??

Comment: If your sound file does not play, check its format and it has to be 30 seconds long.

Comment: No, my sound is ok!  I just need to cancel my own timer in my code before inactive, otherwise  my timer will be active again when the app is active, that's not what I expect to see!

Comment: Ok, so some time is getting active on disfinishlaunchingwithoptions or viewdidload , right ? You can keep bool flag when payload comes keep check and don't active your timer. Else raise your question and share me link so I can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279376/when-pushkit-wake-up-app-how-can-i-know-the-execution-time-is-finished