# When Pushkit wake up app, How can I know the execution time is finished?

Tags: ios, execution-time, pushkit

As we know, for VoIP app, we can use Pushkit to active the app. However, It gives us only max to 30s to execute our code. After the execution time, the app is suspended. I found none method is called before it's suspend, thus, I can not do something to clear my resources. Who can help me?

Comment: Please describe what resources you want to clear. What is the purpose behind this? Do you want to increase more than 30 seconds time or something else. Edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: I just want to know when is the execution time really finished and suspend the app?

Comment: You can get methods in AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive , applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillTerminate

Comment: I tried, but none of above method is called!

Comment: It should be called when sound file playing gets stopped.

Comment: No, It won't. Even  so, how do your code know when sound file stop playing?